# XLDeploy "mvn import deploy" Already imported

Tags: xl-deploy

I'm using XLDeploy "xl-deploy-8.2.1-server-trial-edition" on Windows to test Spring based applications deployment pipeline in a DevOps fashion.
I have Jenkins which executes somes maven goals :

1. to build a war (goal package)
2. the dar (goal xldeploy:generate-deployment-package mapped to phase package)
3. deploy the war to Nexus (goal deploy)
4. import the dar to XLDeploy internal repository (goal xldeploy:import mapped to deploy phase)
5. deploy the war to UAT environment (goal xldeploy:deploy)

I'm using [xldeploy-maven-plugin](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/) release 6.0.x.

I have an issue when executing xldeploy:deploy goal :

```
#mvn clean package deploy xldeploy:deploy
```

XLDeploy server complains about "Already imported version", more exactly :

```
2018-12-05 16:00:03.540 [qtp251546027-45] {username=admin} INFO  c.x.x.p.SourceArtifactEnricher - Going to scan artifact Applications/SGS/SBO/RETAIL/PI/ALPHA/market-securities-account/1.0.0-20181205-155919/market-securities-account
2018-12-05 16:00:09.722 [qtp251546027-46] {username=admin} INFO  c.x.d.r.m.DeployitExceptionMapper - Already imported version 1.0.0-20181205-155919 of application SGS/SBO/RETAIL/PI/ALPHA/market-securities-account
2018-12-05 16:00:09.724 [qtp251546027-46] {username=admin} INFO  c.x.d.r.m.DeployitExceptionMapper - Intercepting DeployitException
com.xebialabs.deployit.service.importer.ImporterException: Already imported version 1.0.0-20181205-155919 of application SGS/SBO/RETAIL/PI/ALPHA/market-securities-account
        at com.xebialabs.deployit.service.importer.ImporterServiceImpl.checkImported(ImporterServiceImpl.java:222)
        at com.xebialabs.deployit.service.importer.ImporterServiceImpl.doImport(ImporterServiceImpl.java:144)
        at com.xebialabs.deployit.service.importer.ImporterServiceImpl.importPackage(ImporterServiceImpl.java:129)
        at com.xebialabs.deployit.core.rest.api.PackageResource.doImport(PackageResource.java:107)
        at com.xebialabs.deployit.core.rest.api.PackageResource.upload(PackageResource.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Indeed Maven through deploy phase (mapped to xldeploy:import goal) has already imported the dar to XLDeploy server and xldeploy:deploy phase try to import again the same dar. Why? According to xldeploy-maven-plugin docs the deploy goal only do deployment but not dar import.

And if I remove the import goal call before, mapped to deploy phase, then just calling :

```
#mvn clean package xldeploy:deploy
```

I have dar imported into XLDeploy server and a deployment plan executed visible in server console :

```
# [Phased plan]
# [Plan phase]
 * Register changes for market-securities-account
   ----------------------------------------------
 1. (100) - Register deployeds  (step: RepositoryUpdateStep, rule: null)
```

Which consists to only register application as deployed but nothing is really deployed on my 2 Tomcats.

But when deploying through Web UI I have the following plan in console :

```
# [Phased plan]
# [Plan phase] Deploy
#########################################################################
# [Serial] Deploy market-securities-account 1.0.0-20181205-165054 on DEV
#########################################################################
    | * Deploy on container VirtualHost (Group default)
    |   -----------------------------------------------
    | 1. ( 10) - Stop Tomcat2  (step: ScriptExecutionStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    | 2. ( 11) - Waiting 10 seconds for Tomcat2 to stop  (step: WaitStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    | 3. ( 60) - Create war settings in market-securities-account.xml on VirtualHost  (step: TemplateArtifactCopyStep, rule: tomcat.WarModule.executeCreate_CREATE)
    | 4. ( 70) - Create market-securities-account on VirtualHost  (step: ArtifactCopyStep, rule: tomcat.WarModule.executeCreate_CREATE)
    |            *checkpoint*  CREATE Infrastructure/DEV/VM_ALPHA2_DEV/Tomcat2/VirtualHost/market-securities-account
    | 5. ( 90) - Start Tomcat2  (step: ScriptExecutionStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    | 6. ( 91) - Waiting 10 seconds for Tomcat2 to start  (step: WaitStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    |-------------------------------------------->
    | * Deploy on container VirtualHost (Group 1)
    |   -----------------------------------------
    | 1. ( 10) - Stop Tomcat1  (step: ScriptExecutionStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    | 2. ( 11) - Waiting 10 seconds for Tomcat1 to stop  (step: WaitStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    | 3. ( 60) - Create war settings in market-securities-account.xml on VirtualHost  (step: TemplateArtifactCopyStep, rule: tomcat.WarModule.executeCreate_CREATE)
    | 4. ( 70) - Create market-securities-account on VirtualHost  (step: ArtifactCopyStep, rule: tomcat.WarModule.executeCreate_CREATE)
    |            *checkpoint*  CREATE Infrastructure/DEV/VM_ALPHA1_DEV/Tomcat1/VirtualHost/market-securities-account
    | 5. ( 90) - Start Tomcat1  (step: ScriptExecutionStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
    | 6. ( 91) - Waiting 10 seconds for Tomcat1 to start  (step: WaitStep, rule: com.xebialabs.deployit.plugin.generic.container.LifeCycleContributor.restartContainers)
# [Plan phase]
 * Register changes for market-securities-account
   ----------------------------------------------
 1. (100) - Register deployeds  (step: RepositoryUpdateStep, rule: null)
```

Why this difference?
Does it comes from the fact that my deployable application is not automatically targeted to environment containers as described in following screenshot?

[XLDeploy deployment plan through UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ubk.png)

When trying with PetClinic war example the containers are automatically targeted, why?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

About deployment plan, the issue was the missing tag "webapp" in VirtualHost CI on Infrastructure part.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The `xldeploy:deploy` goal also executes an import. This makes you should put some logic in Jenkins like (pseudocode):

`if no deploy: execute xldeploy:import
if deploy: execute xldeploy:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an `already imported` error but it was because I was creating a new package but publishing an old one, which indeed had already been imported.